# WPF- Can not get MouseButtonEventArgs.OriginalSource properties

Tags: c#, windows

So sorry this might be a little vague, I'm not really a Windows programmer. I wrote this app a year ago, and it worked fine. Went to update and fix a bug today, and now this part doesn't work. I imagine its got something to do with a new VS version or something because I changed some unrelated variable types from float to double to work with Math.Round(). I've since changed them back and even reloaded the old version from git and it still does not work.

What is supposed to happen: Right click a menu item, set _recentFilesIndex to the index of the selected item, menu pops up, click 'Remove' and the item is removed by index from that list.

The problem is this: `mi` is supposed to be that menu item's text, which is the path to the file. Now its coming back as `null`. `e.OriginalSource` is valid, while debugging I can see the `DataContext` and `Text` property are both in fact the file path. Its not converting it to a `TextBlock` as it did before.

I tried setting it to `e.OriginalSource.DataContext`, but now I can't access that property. (Honestly don't know if I was able before, it's been a year and I've been working on other things). Setting `mi` to `e.OriginalSource` passes the `null` check, but I still can not access any of those properties. I only get `ToString`, `GetType`, `GetHashCode` and `Equals` as properties to it.

So, the question is how do I get the menu items info? It could be the text of the menu item, the DataContext, or the index of the menu item.

*XAML*

```
    <MenuItem Name="mnuRecentLoads" Header="Recent Loads" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}" Click="mnuRecentLoads_OnClick" MouseRightButtonUp="mnuRecentLoads_OnRMBUp" >
        <MenuItem.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="mnuRemove_OnClick" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </ContextMenu >
        </MenuItem.ContextMenu>
    </MenuItem >
```

*CS*

```
    private void mnuRecentLoads_OnRMBUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _recentFilesIndex = -1;
        var mi = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
        if (mi == null)
            return;

        string path = (string) mi.DataContext;
        _recentFilesIndex = mnuRecentLoads.Items.IndexOf(path);
    }
    private void mnuRemove_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_recentFilesIndex < 0)
        {
            _recentFilesIndex = 0;
            return;
        }
        _recentFiles.RemoveAt(_recentFilesIndex);
        mnuRecentLoads.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

Thanks for whatever help you can give.

Comment: In WPF I always use `ObservableCollection`. It automatically refreshes the UI when add or removing items. Perhaps you could use an `ObservableCollection` for the `RecentFiles`

Comment: Yes, RecentFiles is an ObservableCollection, not a list. That works fine.I think I have the refresh in there because I got varying results as I was building this. Windows was not very helpful, sometimes the lists updated, sometimes they didn't, sometimes the bindings worked, sometimes not. Then there was this kind of problem: during debugging I could see in the EventArgs exactly what was selected in the menu, but I could not get that info in the code. This was with dynamic lists and such in menus and list boxes and all that. Hard coded stuff was fine to get at.